# Safari -webkit-transition-property : animating scale and/or background-size

Tags: webkit, css, transition

I'd like to animate a couple of divs with background images. I want them to move position on the page and get larger.

I'm doing this via jQuery by adding a class that, in turn, will trigger Webit's CSS3 transforms.

I started with this:

```
.myStyle {
    width: 240px;
    height: 240px;
    top: 200px;
    -webkit-background-size: 240px;
    -webkit-transition-property: top, -webkit-background-size, width, height;
    -webkit-transition-duration: 1s;
}
```

When adding that style, the DIV changes width and height, moves to the new top position, but the background size remains the same.

So then I tried this:

```
.myStyle {
    top: 200px;
    -webkit-transform: scale(1.5);
    -webkit-transition-property: top, -webkit-transform;
    -webkit-transition-duration: 1s;

}
```

But, same problem. Top animates, but not the scale.

I think (hope) that this is merely a syntax error on my part. Or is it just not possible to transition -webkit properties?

Comment: The common quote (that I can't seem to find a reference to) that says "if you think you've found a bug in the compiler check your code again, you probably didn't" ~ I don't think you found an issue with Webkit but it'll be interesting if you did.

Answer (score 1):

The first code doesn't work because webkit can't animate from one unit dimension (%) to another (px). If you change...

```
.myStyle {
    -webkit-background-size: 150%;
}
```

It should animate, but going from 0 to 100%. A similar thing is happening in your second example, I think.

I'd go about simplifying the code and placing the transition declaration *before* doing the transformation. This allows the element to reverse the transition if you remove the class. Also, if you are scaling things uniformly then -webkit-transform: scale is the way to go.

```
#div {
  /*your css*/
  -webkit-transition: all 1s ease;
}

#div.animated {
  -webkit-transform: -webkit-transform: scale(1.5);
}
```

Comment: that wasn't the original issue...I am actually trying to go from the same unit dimensions. I think the issue was me